# How to use array_merge() using while loop in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I want to merge multiple arrays to a single array, but my first array is not included in the final array.

First array from meta is:

```
array(134) { [0]=> array(6){...}}
```

second array is:

```
array(45) { [0]=> array(6) {..]
```

Third array is:

```
array(121) { [0]=> array(6) {..]
```

Now, my final array is a 166 array as follows:

```
array(166) { [0]=> array(6) {..]
```

However, the result should be a 300 array as follows:

`array(300) { [0]=> array(6) {..]`

This is my code

```
$query_args = array(
            'post_type'=>'instagramtags',
            'posts_per_page'=>-1,
            'orderby'=>'title',
            'order'=>'ASC'
            );
if($_GET['tagname']){$query_args['post__in'][]=$_GET['tagname'];}

$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
// $instagram_array = array();
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    if (is_array($instagram_array)) {
       $instagram_array = array_merge($instagram_array,get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'instagram_array',1));
    }else{
       $instagram_array = get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'instagram_array',1);
    }           

endwhile;

var_dump($instagram_array); die();
```

Comment: I recommend formatting your code to be clean and legible, with consistent indentation and use of spaces. It will make it easier to parse and offer help.

Comment: if i uncomment this array    `$instagram_array = array();` same result 166

Comment: Which is the first array from meta?

Comment: @Emma this code is a bit harder to understand than plain PHP as it uses WordPress, so I'm trying to make OP understand it. He is querying all the instagram posts in `$query` and when iterating through the results, keeps merging `$instragram_array` into itself without any additional filtering. This likely could be done in a much cleaner way.

Comment: A better question to ask is: @AlexLuminoso what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: this return null

Comment: @Emma  thnx a lot

Comment: Generous of you to help @Emma. OP, you still didn't answer my question so that I can help you: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The problem solved after array reconstruction, cache problems